# What are the different ways to say "I'm joking"?

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-usage

I can't recollect if I've ever heard a native speaker say, "I'm joking".

The ones I can remember are:

1. I'm messing with ya
2. I'm just messing/goofing around

What are the other popular ways to convey the same?

Answer (score 2):

"I'm joking" (or "I'm only joking") is extremely common and probably the most idiomatic way to express this.

There are probably countless ways to say the same thing, most suggestions would be slang and these may be particular to dialects of English (British English, American English etc) or even more remotely to regional dialects.

- I'm only teasing
- I'm only fooling with you
- Psyche!
- I'm merely jesting
- Gotcha!
- Fooled you!
- Fished in!

This is by no means an exhaustive list.

Comment: In Britain we speak of "taking the Mickey" - but recently some have declared that this is offensive as demeaning of the Irish. But I have yet to hear an Irishman or woman complain.

Comment: Or "Just pulling your leg."